# Bash error on if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have an error in my bash script when I do a if control between a string and a script read function

```
 #! /bin/bash

test1="false"
while [ $test1 == "false" ]; do
tail -1 demo.txt | while read test
do
echo $test
done
if [ "test" == $test  ]; then
        test1="true"
        echo "end"
else
        test1="true"
        echo "else"

fi
done
```

---

This is the code and the result:

```
    #! /bin/bash

test1="false"
while [ $test1 == "false" ]; do
tail -1 demo.txt | while read test
do
echo $test
done
if [ "test1" == "$test"  ]; then
        test1="true"
        echo "end"
else
        test1="true"
        echo "else"

fi
done

"test2.sh" 17 lines, 215 characters
xxx@xxx:/tmp $ ./test2.sh
test1
else
```

Comment: what is the error shown? Better include that error in the question too.

Comment: `$test` is being set in a subprocess, so `[ "test" == $test  ]` expands to `[ "test" ==   ]`, which results in a syntax error. I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$test` is empty, the `if` becomes:

```
if [ "test" ==   ]; then
```

which normally raises the error:

```
-bash: [: test: unary operator expected
```

You need to enclose your variable in quotes in order for there to be a value when `$test` is empty:

```
if [ "test" == "$test"  ]; then
```

**EDIT:** There are two reasons why `$test` is "empty". The first reason is because `|` creates a subprocess, as Biffen correctly states. When the subprocess exits, all the variables that were set within it go away. In your case, it's not that `$test` is empty; it doesn't even exist. Not at the time you try to use it in `if`.

If you avoid the subprocess (which can be done in several ways), you might still have empty `$test`. The trivial way to avoid it is to write it not as pipe, but as process redirect:

```
while read test
do
    echo $test
done < <(tail -1 demo.txt)
```

This will set the local variable `test` to the first line, it will display it, then it will set it to next line, but there is no next line; `read` fails, but not before it nukes `$test` (so `$test` ends up empty). That it really works as I say, you can check by running this:

```
while read test
do
    realtest="$test"
    echo $test
done < <(tail -1 demo.txt)

echo REALTEST: $realtest
```

and see that `$realtest` now does have the last line of the file (it would not have, if you tried the redirection approach).

However, if you just want to read a single line, why the `while` loop?

```
read test < <(tail -1 demo.txt)
```

Comment: I do this changement. When I print $test I see the value test1 but when I do a control in a if Statement, the code don't go inside the if

Comment: Yes, this is what @Biffen warns about.

Comment: If I show you the sandwich, then turn around and eat it, will you continue to insist "but the sandwich exists, you can see it" after I show you my empty hands? :) Answer edited for more details.

Comment: I used a while Loop because the file I read is a Log file and I Need continue to read just I find a specific word

Comment: @User112638726: Are you sure? `( assignment= ; echo $reference ; set) | grep "assignment\|reference"` only finds `assignment`.

Comment: @Amadan, nope i'm wrong, sorry. Got it confused with awk.